# Populate textbox's with spreadsheet data based on dropdown selection excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a user interface to use on an inventory spreadsheet. In this example, I am trying to display the details of a selected user for edit or delete purposes.

I intend to use a loop to iterate through a column of usernames, stop when it hits the selected username, and populate the shown entities with values obtained from the spreadsheet (these details are in the same row as the username)

Below is an example of what the code will look like.

```
Dim nameRange As Range
Set nameRange = Range("A2:A100")

For Each x In nameRange
    If x = UserFrameUserDropdown.Value Then
        UserFrame_FName.Value = **<code to go here>**
        UserFrame_LName.Value = **<code to go here>**
        UserFrame_Country.Value = **<code to go here>**
        UserFrame_State.Value = **<code to go here>**
        UserFrame_Position.Value = **<code to go here>**
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data you want to populate into your sheet sits neatly in a table next to the column of usernames you can use offset to put the data in

```
Dim nameRange As Range
Set nameRange = Range("A2:A100")

For Each x In nameRange
    If x = UserFrameUserDropdown.Value Then
        UserFrame_FName.Value = x.offset(0, 1)
        UserFrame_LName.Value = x.offset(0, 2)
        UserFrame_Country.Value = x.offset(0, 3)
        UserFrame_State.Value = x.offset(0, 4)
        UserFrame_Position.Value = x.offset(0, 5)
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

This assumes your data for Fname, Lname, Country, State and Position sits in columns B, C, D, E and F against the row pertaining to the username

Comment: I have added the code into the UserFrameUserDropdown_Change sub, but when the value is changed nothing populates.

could it be because x isn't defined as a cell?

Comment: Private Sub UserFrameUserDropdown_Change()
  *Your code Here*
End Sub

Comment: thats where it is. 

I changed the FName line to this based on another answer:

UserFrame_FName.Value = Val(x.offset(0, 2))

The result is that the FName box has a 0 in it.

Comment: you can try that (and yes probably should be explicitly declaring all variable types) but I don't think that would be the cause of your problem. Try stepping through the code and see if it even gets into that if statement?

Comment: Looking at the cell, it is a string - i.e. "Christian" in the event that my name is selected.

Comment: Try x.offset(0, 1).text

Comment: And get rid of the .value after userfram_fbame

Comment: Silenxor, thanks for being so patient. I figured out that the issue was that I was selecting the wrong sheet to populate data from (sheet8 as opposed to Sheet2) and thus the cells were in fact blank. Your original solution was perfect.

Comment: That's odd because I thought you were using a named range thus the sheet would be irrelevant! no worries, glad you eventually got it sorted

Comment: yeah there's actually about 12+ sheets in the workbook. WIll start naming them though so i dont get this happening at later stages of the interface.